# ReactJS - Change navbar color on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, navbar

I have the following code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'React';
import Header from './styles.js';

const HeaderComponent = props => 
{
  const [navBg, setNavBg] = useState(false);
  const isHome = props.name === 'Homepage' ? true : false;

  const changeNavBg = () =>
  {
   window.scrollY >= 800 ? setNavBg(true) : setNavBg(false);
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', changeNavBg);

  return (
  <Header {...(isHome && navBg ? { backgroundColor: '#00008' : {})} />
  )
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when scrolling past 800px, I want my Header to change colors.

Cheers for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple of approaches you could try

###### 1. Use the React [onScroll](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#ui-events) UI event

```js
 return (
   <div onScroll={changeNavBg}>
     <Header {...(isHome && navBg ? { backgroundColor: '#00008' : {})} />
   </div>
 )
```

###### 2. Consider binding the listener to a `useEffect`

```js
import React, {useState} from 'React';
import Header from './styles.js';

const HeaderComponent = props => {
  const [navBg, setNavBg] = useState(false);
  const isHome = props.name === 'Homepage' ? true : false;

  const changeNavBg = () => {
   window.scrollY >= 800 ? setNavBg(true) : setNavBg(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', changeNavBg);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeNavBg);
    }
  }, [])

  return (
  <Header {...(isHome && navBg ? { backgroundColor: '#00008' : {})} />
  )
}
```

Comment: I have actually managed to fix it by passing navBg as a prop in my styles.js and checking there if its set to true & isHome.

I'll mark your answer as correct nonetheless as you deserve it for the given effort.

Thank you.

Comment: Cool. Thanks.  Anyways, here's a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jddnch?file=src/App.js